# __setattr__ only when attribute does not exist

Tags: python

If one overrides the magic method `__getattr__` in a class, the overridden method is called only when the attribute is not found, otherwise default behavior occurs.

But this does not seem to be the case with `__setattr__`, it affects all attributes.

What I am looking for is something which behaves normally when the attribute exists and follows some custom code when the attribute does not exist. And how does one call `super` on `__setattr__` ?

Comment: Well, define a `__setattr__` that checks if the attribute's already there, if so "behave normally" and otherwise add your magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom `__getattr__` to know if the attribute exists or not.

To set the attribute with default behavior, [you do something like](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__):

```
object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
class ClassName(object):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value)
        if hasattr(self, name):
            super(ClassName, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            magic
```

Comment: Note that `hasattr` consults `__getattr__`, i.e. it doesn't check if there's really such an attribute in `__dict__`, `__slots__` or anything but if `self.name` works.

Comment: Indeed, but that was not within scope of the question as I understand it.